# Logitech F710: Does it have cable?

Tags: controllers

Can Logitech F710 be hooked up with a USB cable to computer, instead of using 2.4GHz wireless?

Comment: It's **relevant** to gaming.

Comment: The first part of the question is valid. If the second part of the question is removed, then it is no longer a shopping recommendation.

Comment: For those who aren't aware, since it is relevant, Logitech F710 is a Game Controller, not a mouse (as I intially thought), so I believe this IS a valid question, if not a very good one (Essentially, if you take out the shopping rec part, all you're left with is 'yes' or 'no'.)

Comment: Shopping rec. part removed from the question.

Comment: @WOOOOW I would suggest adding the reason why you want to do this.  Does your controller constantly disconnect, or something along those lines?  You'll probably get better answers if you do that.

Comment: @MBraedley I don't own a controller. Would like to get one. Wireless uses batteries which I don't like. Wireless is also spotty with connections which I don't like. Also, I already have 2.4Ghz band riddled with WiFi access points here, which I don't like.

Comment: Well, Logitech does have a wired option that's pretty similar to the 710.  I would suggest looking at that as an option.

Comment: @MBraedley Was thinking the same thing. Thanks, MBraedley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no ability to use a USB cable with this controller, because there is no USB port.

Answer (score 4):

A cursory glance at [the product page](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/product/f710-wireless-gamepad) reveals no cable attachment other than a 'reciever-extending cable' that connects into the reciever piece.  Though the reviews are vague, it seems this controller does not have a cable connection, nor the capacity to be connected by cable.

The reviews also seem to suggest that the controller has some wireless connection problems - inconsistently through different users, seeming to stem from windows versions or possibly USB Port versions.  USB 2.0 ports seem to be better suited for the controller, and windows 8.1 may have trouble reading the connection.  I suggest reading the reviews for further details.